# Execution time using clock() gives 0 clock cycles

Tags: c, clock

I want to be able to time the execution time of specific parts of an application.
Here is a reduced code to show what I can not understand:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

void fun(){
    double result = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i<200;i++){
        for (int j = 1; j<200;j++){
            result += i/j;              // Random mathematical expression
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    clock_t start, end;

    start = clock();

    fun();

    end = clock();  

    clock_t clocks_taken = (end - start);
    double total_time = ((double)(end - start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC)*1000; //millisec

    printf("Clock cycles: %d. Total time: %lf ms", clocks_taken, total_time);
}
```

Gives the output:

```
Clock cycles: 0. Total time: 0.000000 ms
```

From what I know a clock cycle is a single execution by the processor and a nested forloop should require hundreds of cycles? Or am I mistaking?

I need to be able to measure execution time for tasks that takes around 1 millisec even if the current example does not. If it matters, I am building and running the application in Windows.

Comment: What happens when you debug this process? What are the values of `start`, `end`, `clocks_taken`, `total_time`?

Comment: @Dominique From what I can tell, using printf, `end` and `start` have the same value everytime I try, In the real application they sometimes differ by one but never more than that.

Comment: `int fun()` and `return result;` and then `printf ("result: %d\n", fun());` to ensure your function isn't completely optimized away -- it has no side-effects as it is.

Comment: Did you try using values that are so large that you need to wait for entire seconds for the whole thing to finish?

Comment: @Dominique Just tried using `i<20000` and `j<20000`, it then gives a non zero response that might be correct, but shouldent the clock cycle differ as soon as you do anything at all since it requires the CPU to perform a calculation?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Just tried to return and print it as a `double` but nothing changed.

Comment: @JakobVinkas Your CPU usage clock might tick in very large increments. What is `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` on your platform? The `clock` function is ancient.

Comment: Where did you get the idea that `clock` returns a count of individual instruction cycles?  You can't have gotten that idea from reading the documentation, because that's not what this function does.

Comment: @paddy Oh it is not? I read this: "The C library function clock_t clock(void) returns the number of clock ticks elapsed since the program was launched" In combination with "clock ticks generally refer to the main system clock, which runs at 66 MHz." Maybe I was wrong to view it as a single instrution, but 66MHz should be more than sufficient for my need.

Comment: Try `result += i/j;` --> `result += rand();`.  Do something to affect the _state_.

Answer (score 1):

You don't use the `result`, so it does not need to be computed. Since your function does nothing observable, it takes nearly no time at all. There is no point in benchmarking "toy" code.

Note that "clock cycles" are not CPU clock cycles. They are cycles of some kind of CPU usage timer that may tick in surprisingly large increments. What is `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` on your platform?

Comment: Even if I return the result to main it deos not change anything.

Comment: It changes your problem from benchmarking toy code to benchmarking too little code for your clock resolution. That is a different problem. (Note that returning the result may not be enough. You still aren't using it, so it still doesn't need to be computed. Again, I urge you, do not benchmark toy code.)

Comment: If I print it out as an int is seems to only be 1000.... Is that possible? It would explain my issue. Is there a better way to get a higher resolution? I am using a standard 1 year old company laptop.

Comment: Maybe use a more modern function like `getrusage` or whatever is recommended on your platform. Again, `clock` is ancient.